# How to access Angular 2 object's attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

```
export class Dashboard {
    checked: Object = {users: false, device: false}
    boxClicked(){
        if(checked.users){
            console.log("clicked users");
        }
    }
}
```

Property 'users' does not exist on type 'Object'. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are saying `checked: Object = {users: false, device: false}`
which means that only those members defined 'Object' (the interface) will be visible. So you can not just access 'users'.

You should say `checked: any = {users: false, device: false}`

Comment: You're welcome :-) if it solves your problem you can accept this as the answer to let others know this was correct and has been solved ;-)